# Linux Distro Suggestion

Tags: steam, distro-recommendation

Though I'm thinking it may be not the best place to ask, but there will be more people who came from windows and faced same problems. So, I want to ask it here.

The thing is, my Laptop came with pre-installed Windows 8 and now I desperately trying to use linux on it. Even I tried lightest distros but experience was not as good as I expected. I found out the reason that my PC hardwares were built for windows system.

Note: The main reason for me returning to windows 7 is I can play Dota 2 with 35~40 fps.

I'm giving some specification of my PC below:

- System Manufacturer - Hewlett-Packard
- System Model - HP ProBook 450 G1
- System Type - x64-based PC
- Processor - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2501 Mhz, 2
  Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
- BIOS VersionDate - Hewlett-Packard L74 Ver. 01.47, 7302018
- Total Physical Memory - 3.90 GB

Problems on linux:

- High CPU usage
- Long time on opening apps
- Dota 2 fps drop down to 9~10

It would a great help if anyone can tell me any linux distro where these problem could resolve.

Comment: try another (lighter) ubuntu flavour with another dekstop https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: Tried a lots apt distros with xFce DE even with Lxde, result was upsetting.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Ubuntu.

Recommended system requirements:

2 GHz dual-core processor or better
2 GB system memory
25 GB of free hard drive space
Either a DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
Internet access is helpful

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Recommended system requirements and reality are two different thing